# Paypal hybrid app

Tags: html, cordova, paypal, hybrid-mobile-app, donations

I have managed to integrate a donate paypal button in a Cordova app:

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>
  ...
</form>
```

All works fine except that when the button is pressed, a new window appears and completly covers the app webview making it impossible for the user to go back to the app (the only way is killing the app process), which I think is a very bad user experience.

Things that I've tried:

- `target='_blank'`: same result
- `target='myIFrameName'`: Cross-domain problem
- Post the form via ajax and put result in a div: Form must be calculated on the fly error (with $http.put in ionic, haven't tried with jQuery)

Please, any solution?

The best one would be to have the paypal window inside the current webview not covering header, as I could place a `back` button there (something like iframe solution that could work with cross domain) but also could be with placing a link to go back in the paypal donate page. I haven't investigated deeper enought the paypal plugin at this location: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Cordova-Plugin. anyone knows if it could do the work? (I've already opened an issue there asking for this feature)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a inApp browser ? [Cordova InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

And call `cordova.InAppBrowser.open( url, '_blank', 'location=yes');` on a button click function, or whatever suits you.

```
_blank = inside the app
_system = system's browser( will redirect you from app )
```